# Deep link to my Mobile App from my Website Using App Links approach

Tags: javascript, html, deep-linking, applinks, ios-web-app

I am trying to use the App Links Meta data to add support to deeplink our mobile App from our mobile Web pages and looks like I hit a road block on my first step. The documentation states that the meta tags be included in your head section of the page. [App Links Doc](http://applinks.org/documentation)

```
<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="mysite://docs" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="My Site" />
</head>
```

- Can the meta tags be used only for Facebook and Twitter currently or any site can take advantage of it

I see that there are many tutorials out there on how to handle the URL's once they hit the IOS or Android App.  But I see no info on how this is supposed to be handled on the web site in general( on where it is deeplinked to the mobile App)

- So is including the meta tags the only step required to deep link ?

  Or Do we need to write up some javascript based on some action depending on the device the user is in needs to be redirected to one of the url's that the Mobile App is configured to ?

Like specifying the `window.location = 'mysite://help'` and rerouting to web url if that fails.

As of now the documentation does not seem to be really clear on how to handle this on the web side of any application.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

[facebook Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content) says

> You can add support for App Links to **existing web** content by defining metadata that details how apps link to your content. You need to add the following information to your URLs:

So definitely it can for any site.

**Second**

just include meta tags will be fine.

but something to notice:

facebook applinks doc says

> App Links is an open standard that makes it possible to deep link to content in your app. When someone using your app shares content **via Facebook (or another App Links-enabled app)** you can create a link that makes it possible to jump back into your app from that piece of content.

and when you test your link on your wall, it will be cache.

so when you change your html, you should go to [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to fetch again.

Comment: I have update my answer, thanks for judge my answer, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an applink here: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

the iOS url is a url that cna be used to launch you iOS app - e.g. a schema (app://) used for deeplinking.

this will create a fb.me/xxxxx link which you can use as the app linkin your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a standalone web app (as your question tags suggest) then there's no way to launch it programatically, at the moment. Home-screen web-apps must be launched by the user.

App Links only works between websites and App Store apps, it won't work to launch web apps.

I've seen discussions of the Chromium developers talking about adding this feature (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468226) so hopefully it will appear on Android/Chrome soon, and – fingers crossed – Apple will follow suit one day.